# Nodejs + Puppeteer fails on Ubuntu but works on Windows

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, puppeteer

We were using html-pdf library earlier to generate PDF from html. The library is now deprecated and puppeteer was suggested.

We made the code changes and it worked fine on localhost (Windows 11) machine.

But when we tried to do *npm install* on server (Ubuntu 18), it crashed with this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOMEM
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-09-01T14_19_37_157Z-debug-0.log

1263 info run puppeteer@20.9.0 postinstall node_modules/puppeteer node install.js
1264 info run puppeteer@20.9.0 postinstall { code: undefined, signal: undefined }
1265 verbose stack Error: spawn ENOMEM
1265 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:420:11)
1265 verbose stack     at spawn (node:child_process:733:9)
1265 verbose stack     at /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:18:12
1265 verbose stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
1265 verbose stack     at promiseSpawn (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:17:13)
1265 verbose stack     at spawnWithShell (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:123:10)
1265 verbose stack     at promiseSpawn (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:12:12)
1265 verbose stack     at runScriptPkg (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/lib/run-script-pkg.js:79:13)
1265 verbose stack     at runScript (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/lib/run-script.js:9:16)
1265 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/rebuild.js:363:17)
```

Here is our code to generate pdf:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

export class PdfUtil {
constructor() {
}

public writePdf(filePath: any, htmlData: any) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: 'new' });
            const page = await browser.newPage();

            await page.setContent(htmlData);

            await page.emulateMediaType('screen');

            const pdfOptions = {
                printBackground: true,
                path: filePath, // The path where the PDF will be saved
                margin: { top: '1cm', right: '1cm', bottom: '1cm', left: '1cm' }, // Optional page margins
            };

            await page.pdf(pdfOptions);
            await browser.close();

            resolve(true);
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Environment:

```
Node Version = 16.20.0

"puppeteer": "^20.9.0"
"typescript": "^5.0.4"
```

What is the issue?

**Edit**

I freed and increased the memory and now on **npm install**, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'puppeteer-core/internal/puppeteer-core.js'
```

Comment: ENOMEM means you are running of memory running npm

Comment: You can try to remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`. Then, run `npm install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered the same issue where my application was running flawlessly on localhost but encountered some Puppeteer installation-related issues during deployment on the server. I resolved this issue with the following steps -

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt update && sudo apt install --assume-yes curl
sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
cd /var/www/html
sudo npm install --save puppeteer@~17.1.3
sudo apt install libgconf-2-4 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libgdk- 
pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnss3-dev libxss-dev
```